# Security setting on report type

Tags: reporting, profile, security, custom-report-type

How can I allow reporting on only one report type(there is only one custom object in this report type) for a particular profile in salesforce? All other report types should be hidden/not selectable by this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to the report types are based on the object access to the users.As per the below [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdVoDUAV/field-visibility-in-creating-reports) we don't have any option to hide the report types from some users who have access to the objects.

```
 1) you can't restrict a user to one report type when creating a report, and forbid them from using another
```

You can totally hide the report types that are unused reports as per the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_hide_report_types.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)

Comment: Thank you for providing link. That gives some relevant pointer to my question.